# Not receiving messages after sometime

Tags: windows, winapi, jna

I am using JNA to access `User32` functions (I dont think it has got to do with Java here, more of concept problem). In my application, I have a Java process which communicates with the Canon SDK. To dispatch any messages I am using the below function:

```
private void peekMessage(WinUser.MSG msg) throws InterruptedException {
    int hasMessage = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0); 
    if (hasMessage != 0) {
        lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
        lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
    }
    Thread.sleep(1);
}
```

`peekMessage` is called in a loop and it all works well. Whenever an Image is taken from camera, I get the event and do the rest.

But I have observed, say after about 15 seconds (sometimes never or sometimes just at start) of no activity with camera, taking picture does not give me any download event. Later the whole application becomes unusable as it doesn't get any events from camera.

What can be the reason for this? Please let me know of any other info needed, I can paste the respective code along.

Edit:

Initialization:

```
Map<String, Integer> options = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        lib = User32.INSTANCE;
        hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle("");
        options.put(Library.OPTION_CALLING_CONVENTION, StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION);
        this.EDSDK = (EdSdkLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("EDSDK/dll/EDSDK.dll", EdSdkLibrary.class, options);


 private void runNow() throws InterruptedException {

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        Task task = queue.poll();
        if (task != null) {
            int taskResult = task.call();
            switch (taskResult) {
                case (Task.INITIALIZE_STATE):
                    break;
                case (Task.PROCESS_STATE):
                    break;
                case (Task.TERMINATE_STATE): {
                    //queue.add(new InitializeTask());
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    ;
            }
        }
        getOSEvents();
    }
}
WinUser.MSG msg = new WinUser.MSG();

private void getOSEvents() throws InterruptedException {
    if (isMac) {
        receiveEvents();
    } else {
        peekMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Above, whenever I get my camera event, it add's it to the `queue` and in each loop I check the `queue` to process any `Task`. One more important information: This is a process running on `cmd` and has no window. I just need the events from my camera and nothing else.

The code where I register callback functions:

```
/**
 * Adds handlers.
 */
private void addHandlers() {
    EdSdkLibrary.EdsVoid context = new EdSdkLibrary.EdsVoid(new Pointer(0));
    int result = EDSDK.EdsSetObjectEventHandler(edsCamera, new NativeLong(EdSdkLibrary.kEdsObjectEvent_All), new ObjectEventHandler(), context).intValue();
  //above ObjectEventHandler contains a function "apply" which is set as callback function

    context = new EdSdkLibrary.EdsVoid(new Pointer(0));
    result = EDSDK.EdsSetCameraStateEventHandler(edsCamera, new NativeLong(EdSdkLibrary.kEdsStateEvent_All), new StateEventHandler(), context).intValue();
   //above StateEventHandler contains a function "apply" which is set as callback function


    context = new EdSdkLibrary.EdsVoid(new Pointer(0));
    result = EDSDK.EdsSetPropertyEventHandler(edsCamera, new NativeLong(EdSdkLibrary.kEdsStateEvent_All), new PropertyEventHandler(), context).intValue();
 //above PropertyEventHandler contains a function "apply" which is set as callback function

}
```

Comment: GetMessage() doesn't return until a message is retrieved; you probably want to use PeekMessage() instead. Perhaps the blocking call is gumming up something else in your app.

Comment: What kind of problems can it cause?

Comment: GetMessage can return -1 on error - see [Raymond Chen's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx) article on it.  Maybe that is happening?  Maybe `msg` is not valid for some reason.

Comment: Why is msg a parameter, not a local variable? Also, a [typical message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_loop) behaves slightly differently; don't sleep (no need; GetMessage will block - this might also be the cause of your app becoming 'unusable', whatever that means - is it frozen? Crashes? *Detail please*) and check for -1, not not-equal.

Comment: @DavidM @Steve I do not get -1 at any moment. I have tried it over a hundred runs and I haven't seen `-1` coming. And about loop, I have the while loop outside the method. i.e. `peekMessage` above is repeatedly called in a loop (it checks if its windows and calls `ppekMessage` else calls Mac respective method). Sleep is not reqd. and I have removed it.

Comment: @DavidM Firstly the above code is a part of application (subset), so say in case `GetMessage` gets blocked, it only hangs the respective plugin and not the application. This is where it gets weird: Sometimes `GetMessage` does block it and plugin remains frozen, but I can see events getting dispatched from camera. Sometimes, `GetMessage` keeps returning `1` even though no event is dispatched from camera, i.e. sequentially `1` every time. Finally About `msg`, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ALL messages from ALL windows that belong to this thread, that includes all mouse moves, paints etc. if you aren't rapidly calling this function your message queue will overflow and cause the behavior you describe.

The sleep you definitely don't want as GetMessage yields if no message is waiting.

So if there exists a normal message pump(s) (i.e GetMessage/DispatchMessage) loop somewhere else for this threads window(s) then you should let that pump do most of the work, perhaps use wMsgFilterMin, wMsgFilterMax to just get the event message you require; or even better in this case use peekmessage with PM_NOREMOVE (then you will need your sleep
call as peekmessage returns immediately).

Alternatively provide the hWnd of the window that generates the event to reduce the workload.

Use spy++ to look into which windows this thread owns and what messages are being produced.

To take this answer further please provide answers to: what else is this thread doing and what windows does it own; also is this message pump the only one or do you call into the SDK API where it may be pumping messages too?

Comment: I have updated the post. First ans: Its a console application with no windows. It communicates with canon camera for any events and if at all any image it taken, it downloads it. hence I dont need any events from keyboard or mouse (can I disable them?). Second Ans: This is the only place where I use windows api and no where else. So there is only one message pump. ButI do make calls to canon sdk which **might** be pumping messages too.

Comment: OK so the SDK is probably using a PostThreadMessage type call to post your thread a message. In this case there are probably not too many messages, try tracing out each message if you can't use spy++ and see if you learn anything from that. you can download it here: http://mdb-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html

Comment: There is one more weird behavior:  Sometimes `GetMessage` does block it and plugin remains frozen, but I can see events getting dispatched from camera. Sometimes, GetMessage keeps returning 1 even though no event is dispatched from camera, i.e. sequentially 1 every time.

Comment: Also I am awarding you a bounty because you helped me forward but not accepting because the solution isn't solved yet :)

Comment: Thanks :) Maybe the blocking is screwing up your app? So what happens if you use PeekMessage(msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) and a sleep?

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't help. Infact worse

Comment: Are you following some kind of sample SDK program? if so is that also a console app? it may be expecting a windowed app?? because the way you've got it now I struggle to see why they need to post messages at all

Comment: Probably I need to explain what I am doing. I have the canon sdk with me using which I can control camera, get camera events etc. Now I need to use canon sdk to get the Image as soon as taken from camera. Now in the canon-sdk I need to register some callback functions which are called when an event occurs. I am using `GetMessage` to get those events so that the respective action (downloading picture etc) is taken. And this is a console application.

Comment: Spy++ does not show any messages. Infact for my console windows, it doesn't show the option even to check messages. Is it because its a console application, the option is not shown. In such a case, how do I check it? I am JVM developer and have never worked with win32

Comment: looks like spy++ is useless for console apps :( I dont understand your explanation of how you are using the callbacks and messages, can you give more detail? So are you posting the messages from another application to this one?

Comment: Nope. I just register my callback functions with the canon sdk. Initially I used to think that my callback functions should be called by the sdk as soon as there is an event. But it didn't. Then I wrote the above code using messages where as soon I call `GetMessage`, my callback function gets called. Frankly I do not know who sends these messages to me ( I discovered it through trial and error using win32 api). Please help if you can, I can provide any information needed.

Comment: So which thread is calling you back? Can you post the code where you install the callbacks, and any other SDK API calls you think might be relevant. Check with spy++, maybe the SDK is creating hidden windows to do things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30911/discussion-between-slonik-and-jatin)

Answer (score 0):

There is an OpenSource project wrapping EDSDK with JNA and it has a version of your code that is probably working better:

https://github.com/kritzikratzi/edsdk4j/blob/master/src/edsdk/api/CanonCamera.java#L436

Unfortunately this is not platform independent and specifically the way things work on windows. I am currently in the process of trying to get a MacOS version of things working at:

https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/edsdk4j

Comment: I got it to work eventually. But there were frequent crashes of the canon sdk which were other issues :(